# Getting error deploying C# app on Vista

Tags: c#, windows-vista

My app deploys fine on Win7 pcs, but when i try to run it on Vista i get this error,, any one know what i'm missing here?

```
************** Unntakstekst **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Klassen er ikke registrert (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   ved System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   ved System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   ved System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   ved ServiceTool.CmsForm.InitializeComponent()
   ved ServiceTool.CmsForm..ctor(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 length, Int32 height)
   ved ServiceTool.SetupForm.btn_Start_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   ved System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Innlastede samlinger **************
mscorlib
    Samlingsversjon: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 4.0.30319.269 (RTMGDR.030319-2600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ServiceTool
    Samlingsversjon: 1.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/glennj/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/PAKYY1J5.87Y/CY533GDD.M18/serv..tion_e78e579e9aa1c33a_0001.0000_bed55deccf379cfe/ServiceTool.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Samlingsversjon: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 4.0.30319.278 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Samlingsversjon: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 4.0.30319.282 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Samlingsversjon: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 4.0.30319.269 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
log4net
    Samlingsversjon: 1.2.11.0
    Win32-versjon: 1.2.11.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/glennj/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/PAKYY1J5.87Y/CY533GDD.M18/serv..tion_e78e579e9aa1c33a_0001.0000_bed55deccf379cfe/log4net.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Samlingsversjon: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Samlingsversjon: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking
    Samlingsversjon: 2.5.0.15095
    Win32-versjon: 2.5.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/glennj/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/PAKYY1J5.87Y/CY533GDD.M18/serv..tion_e78e579e9aa1c33a_0001.0000_bed55deccf379cfe/WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DLL
----------------------------------------
AxInterop.MSTSCLib
    Samlingsversjon: 1.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/glennj/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/PAKYY1J5.87Y/CY533GDD.M18/serv..tion_e78e579e9aa1c33a_0001.0000_bed55deccf379cfe/AxInterop.MSTSCLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
Interop.MSTSCLib
    Samlingsversjon: 1.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/glennj/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/PAKYY1J5.87Y/CY533GDD.M18/serv..tion_e78e579e9aa1c33a_0001.0000_bed55deccf379cfe/Interop.MSTSCLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Samlingsversjon: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_no_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Samlingsversjon: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-versjon: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_no_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT-feilsøking **************
Når du skal aktivere JIT-feilsøking (Just In Time), må .config-filen for dette
programmet eller datamaskinen (machine.config) ha
jitDebugging-verdien angitt i delen system.windows.forms.
Programmet må også kompileres med feilsøking
aktivert.

For eksempel:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

Når JIT-feilsøking er aktivert, blir alle ubehandlede unntak
sendt til JIT-feilsøkingen som er registrert på datamaskinen,
i stedet for å bli behandlet av denne dialogboksen.
```

Comment: what com component are you using? im assuming that its not available.

Comment: if GoogleTranslate is correct, message says: "Class is not registered", so you need to register that COM component, so the error is not relative to host OS, but to deployment strategy in general.

Comment: I think it's complaining about Interop.MSTSCLib.DLL. My ?Norwegian isn't up to this unfortunately.

Comment: Windows 7 comes with Remote Desktop 7.0 (and 7.1 was released with Windows 7 SP1) so my guess is that your Vista-machine is still running on 6.0 or 6.1 which might be registed with another CLSID and therefore not available to your application.